# Multiple iOS App Store Updates in under three days

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, software-update

The other day I noticed that some major apps like Instagram, Snapchat, Nike, Facebook, etc. can have multiple updates (sometimes three or more) in only a few days (less than three or four). See this screenshot from Instagram's update schedule below and notice that they've published three updates in the past four days.

[image]

How is this possible? Apple takes at least a week or more per app review (including minor updates). In order to speed up the process to say two or three days, one can submit an Expedited App Review Request. However, Apple only grant these on a limited basis.

**How do apps like this get updated so darn quick? Is Apple playing favorites to major companies and keeping smaller developers at the bottom of their queue?**

Comment: You don't have to wait for an update to be approved before submitting another. It is probably smart to do that, but I don't think there is a restriction.

Comment: @StephenCollins That, to my knowledge is incorrect, as iTunes Connect allows only one app update to be pending at a time (while another is live).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well known that Apple has special relationships with certain developers. It is also possible that they have asked for an "[Expedited App Review](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/app-review/)," though it is unlikely that they have done this for each of these updates. The Expedited Review is supposed to be only for horrific bugs (especially when the app will not open, or if there is a data loss problem) which need to get fixed especially quickly.